# Crosstab Postgres and PHP prepared statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pivot, where-clause

I cannot find a solution to this problem: i have this table:

```
Model    | Date           |  Status    | ...
A        | 21-10-2020     |     Ok     | ...
B        | 21-10-2020     |     Ok     | ...
C        | 21-10-2020     |   Warning  | ...
A        | 19-10-2020     |    Error   | ...
B        | 19-10-2020     |    Warning | ...
...
```

and I want to obtain this:

```
Model    |  Ok   | Warning | Error
A        |   1   |    0    | 1
B        |   1   |   1     | 0
C        |   0   |   1     | 0
...
```

I find a possible solution using crosstab

```
SELECT * FROM  crosstab(
    $$SELECT "Model", "Status", count(1)
    FROM  table
    WHERE "Date" < $$ || $1 || $$
    AND "Date" > $$ || $2 || $$
    GROUP  BY 1,2
    ORDER  BY 1,2
    $$,
    $$VALUES (\'Ok\'::text), (\'Warning\'), (\'Error\')$$ )
    as ct ("Model" text, "Ok" int, "Warning" int,
      "Error" int)'
```

Using a prepared statement in php, where $1 and $2 are dates.
Anyway, I get this error:

> operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone < integer LINE 3: WHERE "Date" < 2020-02-18

The date is treated as an integer, even if I use cast($1 as text) (or date, or timestamp, ..)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to cast your bind values to the proper datatype. I would also recommend using conditional aggregation rather than `crosstab`: it might be a matter of personal taste, but I find that it is much simpler to follow. It is also more flexible (although this does not make a difference in this simple case).

So:

```
select model,
    count(*) filter(where status = 'OK') as ok,
    count(*) filter(where status = 'Warning') as warning,
    count(*) filter(where status = 'Error') as error
from mytable
where date < $1::timestamp and date > $2::timestamp
group by model
```